# UITableView Cells with AutoLayout - Not smooth

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`s. Each cell has a bunch of `UIView`, `UIStackView`, and `UILabel` subviews to build out the design I want.

Everything within the `UITableViewCell` is positioned using AutoLayout, and I allow the UITableView to automatically give height to the cells by doing:

`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

However, because of the complexity of the cell's subview layout, scrolling down the tableView is very laggy/choppy as each cell tries to estimate and build out it's correct height.

I read up on some articles that discuss these issues like:

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5

This inspired me to try a different approach where I would calculate the height of each cell by adding up all the vertical space, and calculating dynamic string height by utilizing functions like the following, and then caching these heights in a dictionary of [IndexPath.row (Int), Row Height (CGFloat)].

```
extension String {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if let height = cellHeightCache[indexPath.row] {
        return height
    } else {
        let data = dataItems[indexPath.row]

        var height: CGFloat = 0

        height += 20 // top padding above text
        height += data.title.heightWithConstrainedWidth(tableView.frame.width - 72 * 2, font: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)) // height of title
        height += 20 // bottom padding below text

        ... // this goes on and on with if statements depending on if the data has a subtitle, image, other properties, etc to get the correct height for *that* cell

        cellHeightCache[indexPath.row] = ceil(height)
        return height
    }

}
```

While this does work, now I am mixing frame calculations, `tableView.frame.width - 72 * 2` with the AutoLayout of the cell's subviews to get the height. And because these are frame calculations, if the user rotates the device or on an iPad brings over the right split screen view, this clearly breaks. I could try and catch all these edge cases and recalculate when the user rotates/changes the size of the screen, but am I missing a way to calculate the height of these cells without using frames?

Is there anyway just using AutoLayout positioning I can calculate the height of the cells in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function?

Thanks

Comment: I believe the cause is somewhere else. Could you please provide cellForRowAtIndexPath method implementation in your question?

Comment: Also, maybe you can profile your app using "Core Animation" tool to see at which pieces of code the performance is eaten the most during scrolling.

Comment: @DisableR in talking with other developer friends of mine who have apps that use AutoLayout and estimated heights they too experience a lag/jerkiness when they scroll. I also created a demo app - that JUST has 2 labels in a custom cell (using AutoLayout) and there was also lag/jerk there to prove it was related to the estimated height not some complex layout.

Comment: Did you try to call sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(yourWidth, Float.max)) on your labels instead of measuring strings directly? It could be more performant.

Comment: @DisableR once I go the frames route, everything is extremely performant. It's when I don't do any measuring and try to go the pure AutoLayout route that things are not smooth. Just want to make sure you know what I'm getting at here - is there a way to measure height for autolayout cells besides dealing with frames where I don't have to remeasure when the user rotates/etc.

Comment: @Alex You can create a backing cell(instantiate the cell in code) and make it layout with the real data. You'd do it in the heightForRow method. I am, too, suspicious that autolayout is the problem. There are many things that can clog the scrolling in the UITableView. A screenshot of the XIB cells / cellForRowAtIndexPath function would help.